# How can I transform data in xlsx file removing merge in cells and transposing some columns to ingest data in SQL Server using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, xlsx

I have an As-Is spreadsheet data source with merge applied in some columns and for weekly data columns are used in incremental format, e.g. for the 2019W12 the next column will be populated (R column).

*As-Is Spreadsheet Data Source*

[image: As-Is Spreadsheet Data Source]

I need parse the spreadsheet content and load into SQL Server table using SSIS and proposed format is:

*Proposed Spreadsheet Data Transformation*

[image: Proposed Spreadsheet Data Transformation]

I've tried some alternatives such as apply transformation in SSIS, but column increment case exception in next week load job, I tried to parse and split spreadsheet data with Python (xlrd) but without success to transpose and associate data from columns F to 'N' with columns from A to E. Does anybody faced this type of problem to ingest spreadsheet data using SSIS into SQL Server or have another logical way to transform data before ingestion?

Comment: How does the data get into the spreadsheet in the first place? Can you go back and get the raw data that was used to build the spreadsheet? The only other way I can think of doing it is to create the transformation in Excel using VBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Splitting Question into sub tasks**

Based on your question there are three main functionalities that you are looking to achieve:

1. Finding an efficient way to manipulate Excel files
2. Unmerge Cells and fill duplicates values
3. Transpose Rows into Columns

**Possible solution**

In order to perform a complex transformation you have to do this using one of the following approaches because provides all functionalities that can be done in Microsoft Excel:

1. .Net Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library (C# or VB.NET)
2. Excel VBA

The solution you are looking for is complex and very specific to the issue, you have to implement the logic at your own. I will provide some links that can helps you to achieve that:

**Helpful Links**

*Unmerge Cells and fill duplicates values*

- [How To Unmerge Cells And Fill With Duplicate Values In Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1139-excel-unmerge-cells-and-fill.html) *(This link describe the process manually and using VBA)*
- [Unmerging excel rows, and duplicate data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215022/unmerging-excel-rows-and-duplicate-data)
- [How to unmerge and fill cells in an excel file while loading into datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48982664/how-to-unmerge-and-fill-cells-in-an-excel-file-while-loading-into-datatable)
- [Unmerge and fill values - if the cells are merged to the same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648099/unmerge-and-fill-values-if-the-cells-are-merged-to-the-same-column)

*Manipulating Excel files using C#*

- [C# Excel Interop: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://www.dotnetperls.com/excel)
- [C# Excel Tutorial](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-tutorial.htm)
- [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C#.NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/302084/how-to-automate-microsoft-excel-from-microsoft-visual-c-net)
- [Working with Excel Using C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/696864/Working-with-Excel-Using-Csharp)
- [Read Excel File in C#](https://coderwall.com/p/app3ya/read-excel-file-in-c)

*Transpose Excel Rows*

- [C# - Transpose excel table using Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592498/c-sharp-transpose-excel-table-using-interop)
- [C# Transpose() method to transpose rows and columns in excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838403/c-sharp-transpose-method-to-transpose-rows-and-columns-in-excel-sheet)
- [Transpose values in excel using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852602/transpose-values-in-excel-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Hi Hadi, thank you very much. Take a looking in the links shared by you, I could solve quickly with VBA and C#. I will keep with C# option due possibility to execute a script task in SSIS. I was looking for a big problem, but decompose this in small problem help to make right questions to find similar cases in the web. Thank you for the Lessons Learned too.